# Is it possible in Excel or VBA to have one column be the running total of times completed?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an independent cell that is hardcoded for a start time: 9:00 a.m.

Then, I have two more columns(not exclusively, but they're the ones that pertain to this issue). One column will be for time completed. The other is for the number of hours for that item to complete.

So, the first item, based off a 1 hour time to complete value, would show 10:00am.
Then, if the next item shows 2 hours to complete, it would show 12:00am and so forth to the end of the data.

I've tried this code, and while it works for only the first cell, I can't get it to replicate when dragging down the rest of the cells.

```
=TIME(HOUR(C1)+D3,MINUTE(0),SECOND(0))
```

Here is a data sample and link to a google sheet of it:

[image]

[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/111nEbbmqY4gen__Oi-2t_QonO0Gi35RvU4mD_8kNeCU/edit?usp=sharing)

This is what I want it to show automatically:

[image]

Comment: is it sufficient to refer to `C1` as `C$1` to lock its rowwise ref?

Comment: Almost. it fills all values with 9am + whatever hour completion for that row as opposed to building off the time from the previous row. So row 4 would show time_total = 11am, row 5 would show 10am.

Comment: Added an image to op about the data it should show.

Comment: Does this work? `=TIME(HOUR(C$1)+SUM(D$3:D3),MINUTE(0),SECOND(0))`

Comment: That's okay.  The suggested solution is a bit ugly but hopefully okay for small amounts of data.  There are more efficient approaches but I think they would all involve a small amount of reorganising the data (like shifting rows 3-6 down by one and moving 9:00AM to B3).